# pandas value_counts() returning incorrect counts

Tags: python, pandas, count

I was wondering if anyone else has ever experienced value_counts() returning incorrect counts. I have two variables, Pass and Fail, and when I use value_counts() it is returning the correct total but the wrong number for each variable.

The data in the data frame is for samples made with different sample preparation methods (A-G) and then tested on different testing machines (numbered 1-5; they run the same test we just have 5 different ones so we can run more tests) and I am trying to compare both the method and testers by putting the pass % into a pivot table. I would like to be able to do this for different sample materials as well so I have been trying to write the pass % function in a separate script so that I can call it to each material's script if that makes sense.

The pass % function is as follows:

```
def pass_percent(df_copy):
   pds = df_copy.value_counts()
   p = pds['PASS']
   try:
       f = pds['FAIL']
   except:
       f = 0
   print(pds)
   print(p)
   print(f)
   pass_pc = p/(p+f) *100
   print(pass_pc)
   return pass_pc
```

And then within the individual material script (e.g. material 1A) I have (among a few other things to tidy up the data frame before this - essentially getting rid of columns I don't need from the testing outputs):

```
from pass_pc_function import pass_percent
mat_1A = pd.pivot_table(df_copy, index='Prep_Method', columns='Test_Machine', aggfunc=pass_percent)
```

An example of what is happening is, for Material 1A I have 100 tests of Prep_Method A on Test_Machine 1 of which 65 passed and 35 failed, so a 65% pass rate. But value_counts() is returning 56 passes and 44 fails (so the total is still 100 which is correct but for some reason it is counting 9 passes as fails). This is just an example, I have much larger data sets than this but this is essentially what is happening.

I thought perhaps it could be a white space issue so I also have the line:

`df_copy.columns = [x.strip() for x in df_copy.columns]`

in my M1A script. However I am still getting this strange error.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Results example as requested

```
PASS    31
FAIL    27
Name: Result, dtype: int64
31
27
53.44827586206896

                 Result                                  
Test_Machine          1          2          3           4
Prep_Method                                              
A             53.448276  89.655172  93.478261   97.916667
B             87.050360  90.833333  91.596639   97.468354
C             83.333333  93.150685  98.305085  100.000000
D             85.207101  94.339623  95.652174   97.163121
E             87.901701  96.310680  95.961538   98.655462
F             73.958333  82.178218  86.166008   93.750000
G             80.000000  91.743119  89.622642   98.529412
```

Comment: Can you include a [MRE] that shows the wrong results? The function *pass_percent* is not valid python.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to Python so I'm not entirely sure what you mean despite reading the linked page.

I actually don't have any data for test machine 5 right now but this is the top line of the pivot table I get:

                   Result                                  
Test_Machine          1          2          3           4
Prep_Method                                              
A             53.448276  89.655172  93.478261   97.916667

Made from the data:
PASS    31
FAIL    27
Name: Result, dtype: int64
31
27
53.44827586206896
etc

Comment: Sorry, that is formatted really badly but I don't know how to make it better, again, I am really new here too sorry, @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: Welcome to SO @Em23. I don't think `value_counts()` does what you expect it to? It counts only **unique** values. And from the example you are giving us, I cannot see that there is a column named `"PASS"` or `"FAIL"`?

Comment: Hi Karl. Sorry I didn't clarify, PASS and FAIL come from a column called 'Result'. I have been trying to track the issue back to the root cause and it seems value_counts is working find, but my data is being changed. The data is held on an sql database and somewhere along the line the pass/fails are being changed. I simply printed `data1 = df[df['Prep_Method'] == 'A']` and `data2 = data1[data1['Test_Machine'] == 1]` `data2.to_csv('test.csv')` and my data is being changed wildly (if I put the conditions in the query it's fine) so it seems I have an entirely different issue that I thought.